# Android RemoteViews, how to set ScaleType of an ImageView inside a widget?

Tags: android, widget, imageview

I am developing a widget with an image on the rigth side, which can be choosen by the user in one of the settings screen.
The image can then be set from the user with the ImageView.setScaleType("CENTER"). That works.
The URL of the image is then stored in the preferences as URL, and also as Base64 encoded String of the Bitmap (cause I want to shrink the image and the user can rotate it in the settings)

In the widget, I load the image. That works fine. With the URI and with the Bitmap too.
The ScaleType of the ImageView is set as well to a fixed value in the Layout, works too.

**But how can I define the ScaleType of the ImageView in the widget programmatically?
Cause I want to set the ScaleType to the value, the user has choosen in the settings. With RemoteViews, we cannot get the ImageView...**

I tried:

---

> myRemoteViews.setString(R.id.myImage, "setScaleType", "CENTER");

---

The logfile says: The function setScaleType is not possible for ImageView.

Does someone know how to make this definition inside the AppWidget?

Answer (score 82):

You can use this segment to set scale type for Image View programatically..

```
 imgview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: This is how to set the scale type for a normal `ImageView`, but the questioner was asking about in a `RemoteViews`.

Answer (score 11):

If you look at the source code of `ImageView`, you can see the `setScaleType` method lacks the `@android.view.RemotableViewMethod` annotation, so it can't be called through the `RemoteViews` interface.

There's a workaround for this limitation, but it's not pretty: define a different layout XML for each ScaleType you want, and choose between them just before you create the `RemoteViews`. If your layout is complex, or you have more than one view to apply this workaround to, you might want to use [`RemoteViews.addView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#addView%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) to add the particular `ImageView` layout inside the main layout.

I'm using this workaround (with `addView`) for appwidgets in my app [Showr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr). The problem with this method is that the stock launcher has a bug: if you *change* the scale type of an existing appwidget by creating a new `RemoteViews` and calling `addView` to add a different `ImageView` layout to it, it doesn't always realise the layout has changed.

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but what about extending `ImageView` and adding the annotation, then your custom `ImageView` would call through to `super.setScaleType(...)`

Comment: You can't use your own classes in a `RemoteViews`, only the ones  built into the system.

Answer (score 1):

Since the is no simple way to call `setScaleType` on the remove view the work around I came up with was making three imageViews in my layout and then changing the visibility of the ones that don't have the scale type selected by the user:

```
    // first I declared a map to associate preference values with imageView ids

    private static final HashMap<Integer,Integer> widgetImageViewIds;

    static {
        widgetImageViewIds = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        widgetImageViewIds.put(MyAppPreferences.PREF_ALIGN_START, R.id.imageViewStart);
        widgetImageViewIds.put(MyAppPreferences.PREF_ALIGN_CENTER, R.id.imageViewCenter);
        widgetImageViewIds.put(MyAppPreferences.PREF_ALIGN_END, R.id.imageViewEnd);
    }

    ...

    // then when I update my widget show/hide the widgets based on the preference

    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : widgetImageViewIds.entrySet()) {
        Integer imageViewAlignment = entry.getKey();
        Integer imageViewId = entry.getValue();
        views.setViewVisibility(imageViewId, imageViewAlignment.intValue() != imageAlignmentPreferenceValue ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
```